# Peek on `PrefetchDataset`

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Is it possible to peek at a `PrefetchDataset`? I.e. to check whether there are more elements in the queue/buffer (this should block if the input dataset is not accessed yet), without actually getting the next element.

(This could be relevant for synchronized training with Horovod. But it might be useful in general.)